# How to declare a struct in c?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization

I am following this [example](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~wolber/SoftwareDev/C/CStructs.htm), and my program looks like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

struct Foo
{
    int x;
    int array[100];
}; 


struct Foo f;
f.x = 54;
f.array[3]=9;

void print(void){

    printf("%u", f.x);
}

int main(){
    print();
}
```

However, I am getting errors when compiling using `make example_1`:

```
example_1.c:13:1: error: unknown type name 'f'
f.x = 54;
^
example_1.c:13:2: error: expected identifier or '('
f.x = 54;
 ^
example_1.c:14:1: error: unknown type name 'f'
f.array[3]=9;
^
example_1.c:14:2: error: expected identifier or '('
f.array[3]=9;
 ^
4 errors generated.
make: *** [example_1] Error 1
```

What is the problem with this declaration of struct?

Comment: You cannot write executable code outside of a function. Put the 3 lines `struct Foo f; ... f.array[3]=9` inside `main()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f.x = 54;
f.array[3]=9;
```

Should be inside some function. You can not write program flow outside function in global scope except initialization.

To initialize it globally, use

```
struct Foo f = {54, {0, 0, 0, 9}};
```

[live code here](http://ideone.com/ZJ92R9)

In C99, you can also write

```
struct Foo f = {.x=54, .array[3] = 9 };
```

[live code here](http://ideone.com/dkJJeh)

---

The example link you mentioned says:

> struct Foo f;  // automatic allocation, all fields placed on **stack**
>   
> `f.x = 54;`
> `f.array[3]=9;`

Use of word stack suggests it is begin used inside a local function like below:

```
void bar()
{
  struct Foo f;
  f.x = 54;
  f.array[3]=9;
  do_something_with(f);
}
```

[live example here](http://ideone.com/5WinpG)

Answer (score 2):

You can only initialize a structure variable at the point of its decleration.

You can initialize it like this:

```
struct Foo f = {54, {0, 0, 0 9}};
```

or using the C99 feature `designated initializers`:

```
struct Foo f = {.x = 54, .array[3] = 9};
```

The second way to do it is alot clearer but unfortunately C99 isn't as widely available as C89. The GNU compiler fully supports C99. Microsoft's compiler does not support any C standard above C89. C++ also doesn't this feature.

So if you want the code to compile with C++ compilers or Microsofts C compiler you should use the first version. If you are writing your code purely for gcc and don't much about Microsoft's development tools you can use the second version.

You can also assign each member individually in a function:

```
void function(void)
{
    f.x = 54;
    f.array[3] = 9;
}
```

But you cannot do it globably.

Comment: At the time I started to write this the other answer didn't suggest `designated initializers`. After I posted this I noticed the other answer was edited to include that. This answer seems redundant now. I don't know what to do.